# Does studying university math improve (your ability for) second language acquisition?

Tags: education-statistics

I'm asking solely about the direction whether studying math ⇒ improves your competence at acquire *second* languages (L2). "University math" signifies math that an undergraduate math major would take in university.

I'm NOT asking about 1. L1 acquisition.

2. or the other direction, whether your math skills are improved ⇐ acquiring second languages. ["While bilinguals and monolinguals solved the problems with equal accuracy and took about the same amount of time on arithmetic with familiar sets of operations, bilinguals beat out monolinguals, on average, by about half a second on novel problems."](https://psmag.com/social-justice/language-trains-brain-math-91289)

Comment: A fine question, even if it is unlikely nobody has researched this. Do you have a reason to assume that mathematics would be particularly helpful? In general, transfer effects from learning mathematics are small, as far as I know.

Comment: A quick search finds this as a source that might have something: https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2010-24814-001

Comment: A very quick search does not find a relevant article; effect of language on mathematics learning is much more popular as a research question than the converse.

Comment: @Tommi "Do you have a reason to assume that mathematics would be particularly helpful?" Not from any peer reviewed journal. I've heard this contention from various teachers and professors.

Comment: Only if the math is taught in the language you wish to acquire. Otherwise, it is not helpful. All languages are different.